# InvalidStateError in IE for esri-leaflet

Tags: esri-leaflet

I have a map that works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but gets stuck on the httpRequest in IE 11.

I get InvalidStateError in here on httpRequest.timeout = context.options.timeout.

I am a bit lost, not familiar with Request.js and haven't had much luck find any issues like this.

```
function xmlHttpPost (url, params, callback, context) {
  var httpRequest = createRequest(callback, context);

  if (typeof context !== 'undefined' && context !== null) {
    if (typeof context.options !== 'undefined') {
      httpRequest.timeout = context.options.timeout;
    }
  }
```

The Global code from the Call stack in the IE debugger shows my query statement as well.

```
          // style each zone and add to layer group
      query.run(function (error, response) {
          L.geoJson(response, {
              style: function (feature) {
                  switch (feature.properties.ZONING_) {
                      case 'CN': return { fillColor: '#FF7800', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                      case 'CG': return { fillColor: '#DF73FF', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                      case 'S-T4': return { fillColor: '#FFFF73', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                      case 'S-T5': return { fillColor: '#FFFF73', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                      case 'S-T5-2': return { fillColor: '#FFFF73', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                      case 'S-T5-1': return { fillColor: '#FFFF73', stroke: false, fillOpacity: 0.35 };
                  }
              }
          }).addTo(zoningLayerGroup);
      });
```

Comment: what version of leaflet/esri-leaflet?  can you post a fiddle?

Comment: leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2 and leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.8. I was able to move the 'httpRequest.open' lines after the 'httpRequest.send' lines and got no errors in IE, but also did not edit the data. So I didn't do it right, but that seems to be the problem, some comments here about that issue, https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/179. I will try to get it going in a fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an IE10/11 specific bug (problem isn't reproducible in 9 or Edge), but with your help i was able to identify a [workaround](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/pull/770).

---

The fix has been included in esri-leaflet [`2.0.0`](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/wiki/Esri-Leaflet-2.0.0-Announcement)